# API - DELETE method is not working with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api

```
const init = () => {


    document.querySelector("#newTask").addEventListener("click", addNewTask);
    //document.querySelector("#deleteTask").addEventListener("click", deleteData);
    getDataa();

};

const getDataa = () => {

    addNewTask();

    const url = "https://ghu8xhzgfe.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tasks/2877332";
    fetch(url, {
            method: "GET",
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                "x-api-key": "Itcheui2tB58SlUGe8rrP8mskudGsNDT9nfKKG9S",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }


        })
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            // Loop to access all rows




            for (i = 0; i <= data.ScannedCount; i++) {

                let text = "";
                //const items = data.Items[i].Description;

                Array.from(data.Items).forEach(myFunction);


                // display the data to the end user and link it to the index page
                document.getElementById("displayTable").innerHTML = text;

                function myFunction(item, index) {
                    text += ' <button type="button" class="btn" id="task" onclick="deleteData()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>' + "  " + data.Items[index].Description + "<br>";

                }

            }




        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });


}

const deleteData = () => {
    console.log("delete data ");


    //let deleteDescription = document.querySelector("#task").value;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "https://ghu8xhzgfe.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tasks/";
    let studentId = "2877332";
    let taskDescription = document.querySelector("#task").value;
    fetch(url, {
            method: 'DELETE',

            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "x-api-key": "Itcheui2tB58SlUGe8rrP8mskudGsNDT9nfKKG9S",

            },

            body: {
                'StudentId': 'studentId',
                'Description': 'taskDescription',
                'version': 'JSON',
            }


        })
        .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
                console.log("DELETE request successful");
                getDataa();
                return res
            } else {
                console.log("DELETE request unsuccessful");
            }
            return res
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then()
        .catch(error => console.log(error))


}


const addNewTask = () => {
    console.log("Adding a new task...");

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "https://ghu8xhzgfe.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/tasks";
    let apiKey = "Itcheui2tB58SlUGe8rrP8mskudGsNDT9nfKKG9S";
    let studentId = "2877332";
    let taskDescription = document.querySelector("#task").value;
    let params = {
        StudentId: studentId,
        Description: taskDescription
    };
    xhr.open("post", url);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", apiKey);



    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {

        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log("New record was added ...");



        }
    }
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
};
window.onload = init;
```

Please, could you help with the delete function is not working as expected
Please, see attached file

[image]

Comment: the picture says "Delete request successful" - what makes you think it failed

Comment: of course `'StudentId': 'studentId',` sets the StudentId to literally the string `"studentId"` rather than the value in the variable `studentId` - but surely you aren't actually doing that - and why are you creating an XMLHttpRequest when you are using fetch?

Comment: You may find some interesting output in your console if you do `.then(res => res.json()).then(console.log)` instead of `.then(res => res.json()).then()`

Comment: Nothing has been deleted as you see the array(4) still have 4 data instead of 3

Comment: the issue is on the server then ... did you do as I suggested with the response?

Comment: I was able to delete the data from the server ... DELETE is working correctly on the server but not on my web interface using the button

Comment: so what is the response in `res.json()` when you try, have you tried the code I suggested to output the result, it may surprise you what the console.log will output? did you fix the issue in my second comment, since you're not sending what you think you are with that code

Comment: Yup  I have tried it and, here is what I got: 
{errorType: 'ValidationException', errorMessage: 'The provided key element does not match the schema', trace: Array(11)}
errorMessage: "The provided key element does not match the schema"
errorType: "ValidationException"

Comment: The issue is with the taskDescription for some reason I am sending a blank or, null object ... how could get the object?

Comment: the issue is you're sending strings, not the values of the variables you've created - as I mentioned in the 2nd comment - have you tried console.log the result of res.json() yet ... you'll get information from that console.log that will surprise you

Comment: Yup I have tried it and, here is what I got: {errorType: 'ValidationException', errorMessage: 'The provided key element does not match the schema', trace: Array(11)} errorMessage: "The provided key element does not match the schema" errorType: "ValidationException

Comment: exactly, because you're sending `'StudentId': 'studentId'` ... literally the value `studentId` rather than what you intended `'StudentId': 2877332`

Comment: You are right ... but not sure how do I get the value of the variable? could you help

Comment: `'StudentId': studentId` notice the lack of quotes ... also, you'll want to `JSON.stringify` what you are sending as a `body` - so that you send JSON, not an Object

Comment: Alright, I have changed that ... and, the issue persists? what should I do for the Description variable?

Comment: Please, could you correct it in my code so, I can see my issue? appreciate it

Comment: did you set the body to JSON, or is it still an object?

Comment: How could I set the body to JSON?

Comment: I told you 4 minutes ago ... JSON.stringify ... answer posted

Comment: I will need only fix the taskDesctioption then, I should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

Your code is sending an Object in the body

You're also setting the values of the properties to the literal strings 'studentId' and 'taskDescription'

The following may fix your issue

```
  body: JSON.stringify({
    'StudentId': studentId,
    'Description': taskDescription,
    'version': 'JSON',
  })
```

Comment: Thank you ,, it seems that help my code but, now I am getting a new error message: 
{errorType: 'ValidationException', errorMessage: 'One or more parameter values are not valid. The At…t contain an empty string value. Key: Description', trace: Array(11)}

Comment: How could I get tge taskDescription value?